# Error:incomparable types: String cannot be converted into int

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Name {

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userName;
    int userAge;

    System.out.println("What is your full name?");
    userName = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("What is your age?");
    userAge = in.nextLine();

    System.out.println("You're " + userName + " and you are " + userAge + "   years old");
   }
}
```

This error keeps popping up and i can't find a mistake. Plz help. I am a newbie and i have done my research on this issue. I couldn't find an issue and i have been working over this code for a good week. I want to rip my hair out!!

Comment: If you rip your hair out for such trivial issues, you would have none left in a couple of weeks. I would suggest you use an IDE with debugging facilities. It makes life much simpler, for such issues

Comment: [IDE or Integrated Development Environment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment). If you want to become a better programmer, you will need at least two things: strong will for do research of stuff, and an even stronger will for write code, test, see it fail, fix it, fail, fix it again... until it works and you earn exp. But don't worry, it becomes *fun*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`userAge` is an `int` and you're using `in.nextLine()` to assign a value to it. `Scanner#nextLine` returns a `String`, which is incompatible with `int`. USe`Scanner#nextInt` instead:

```
userAge = in.nextInt();
in.nextLine();
```

Comment: THX SOO MUCH I LOVE U (NO HOMO)

Answer (score 0):

One more way of doing it is:

```
userAge = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine().trim());
```

Java is a strongly typed language, so you cannot assign a one type to another type without typecasting. In this case `in.nextLine()` returns a String which can't be assigned directly to int datatype